# Different layouts for child items

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am developing an app which contain a expandable list view.

In my expandable list view, I want to set different layout for each child view.

My custom Expandable list adapter is given below:

```
public Object getGroup(int arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return menu[arg0];
}

public int getGroupCount()
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return menu.length;
}

public long getGroupId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

public View getGroupView(int position, boolean arg1, View view, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    if(view==null)
    {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_head, null);

    }
    TextView head = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text_view_head);
    head.setText(menu[position]);
    return view;
}

public Object getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getChildId(int arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean arg2, View childView,
        ViewGroup parent) 
{
    if(childView==null)
    {
        childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_child, null, false);
    }

    return childView;
}
```

But click on the list it doesn't show its child.

Answer (score 2):

You can create you own adapter:

```
 public class ExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<String> groups;
        private ArrayList<ArrayList<Expand>> expand;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public ExpandableAdapter(Context context, 
                            ArrayList<String> groups,
                            ArrayList<ArrayList<Expand>> expand) { 
            this.context = context;
            this.groups = groups;
            this.expand = expand;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
        }
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return expand.get( groupPosition ).get( childPosition );
        }

        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return (long)( groupPosition*50+childPosition );
        }
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, 
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = null;
            if( convertView != null )
                v = convertView;
            else
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, parent, false); 
            Expand c = (Expand)getChild( groupPosition, childPosition);
            TextView color = (TextView)v.findViewById( R.id.grp_child_primero);
            if( color != null )
                color.setText( c.getTitulo());
            TextView rgb = (TextView)v.findViewById( R.id.grp_child_segundo);
            if( rgb != null )
                rgb.setText( c.getDato());
            return v;
        }

        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return expand.get( groupPosition ).size();
        }
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return groups.get( groupPosition );        
        }
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return groups.size();
        }

        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return (long)( groupPosition*50 );
        } 
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, 
                                                                            ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = null;
            if( convertView != null )
                v = convertView;
            else
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, parent, false); 
            String gt = (String)getGroup( groupPosition );
            TextView expandGroup = (TextView)v.findViewById( R.id.grp_child_primero);
            if( gt != null )
                expandGroup.setText( gt );
            return v;
        }
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        } 
        public void onGroupCollapsed (int groupPosition) {} 
        public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {}

    }
```

With one xml for rows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/negro">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/grp_child_primero"
         android:focusable="false"
         android:textSize="20sp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
         android:background="@drawable/negro"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/grp_child_segundo"
         android:focusable="false"
         android:textSize="18sp"
         android:textStyle="normal"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
         android:background="@drawable/negro"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And other for groups:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/negro">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/grp_child_primero"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:paddingLeft="30dp"
         android:textSize="20sp"
         android:textColor="@drawable/blanco"
         android:textStyle="normal"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
         android:background="@drawable/negro"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And after that:

```
ExpandAdapter youadapter = new ExpandAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
        namesGroups, nameChilds);
setListAdapter(youadapter);
```

Where namesGroups and nameChilds are list the data for rows and groups.
With the method setListAdapter, you can set the adapter to the ExpandableListActivity ;)
And finally Expand class is a simple POJO:

```
public class Expand {
    public String titulo = null;
    public String dato = null;

    public Expand( String titulo, String dato) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.dato = dato;
    }
    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }
    public String getDato() {
        return dato;
    }
}
```

Looks primarily as getChildView method (in ExpandableAdapter class) is implemented, and some inside if you do not think it is complicated to implement what you want